# ModalController dismiss function call other component in ionic or angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, components, dismiss

```
**other component html file where want call dismiss function**                            
<ion-col size="2" class="btn-center">
    <ion-buttons class="btn-close">
      <ion-button (click)="onCloseComponent()">
        <ion-img src="/assets/img/closebtn.svg"></ion-img>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-col>
```

**component ts which is  parent**

```
  async presentTextModal() {
this.blocksToolsTextComponentModal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: BlocksToolsTextComponent,
  cssClass: 'blocks-tools-text',
  swipeToClose: true,
  initialBreakpoint: 0.3,

  breakpoints: [0, 0.3],
});
return await this.blocksToolsTextComponentModal.present();
```

}

Hello everyone, I want to call the dismiss function from another component by clicking on another component. A function that calls a modal is in one component. I even need to have a click button in the summoned modal that closes the modal. That is, in the opened component I call the dismiss function. I am using modalController ionic in the framework.  thank you for advice

Comment: I found the answer. It turns out you can call that component directly using the controller.

Comment: onCloseComponent() {
    this.modalController.dismiss();
  }